# Phpmyadmin input type for gender?

Tags: php, mysql

I created a database and table (name, email, pw, sex) and set all the input types to varchar (50) but was wondering how to set the input type for the select sex field. I want to use 3 options (man, woman, open). What input type would that be? i.e. boolean etc...

also what do you think the pros and cons are of using your email as your username?

Comment: Please don't ask 2 questions in one

Comment: ENUM should be great <option value = "m"> (m for male, f for female, o for open).

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the [enum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) type?

Answer (score 0):

boolean should be sufficient for the sex field

```
1=male
0=female
NULL=open
```

e-mail as username is often a good choice because you can validate it via validation link and no one forgets his own e-mail-adress